# LINQ ignoring where if someobject is null

Tags: c#

Consider the following function

```
 public static string UpdateCommand<T>(List<string> Except=null,List<string> Only=null)
        {
           if (Except != null && Only != null)
              {
                 throw new Exception();
              }

        List<PropertyInfo> properties = typeof(T).GetProperties().ToList();


        if (Except != null)
        {
            for (int i = properties.Count; i-- > 0; )
            {
                if (Except.Contains(properties[i].Name)) properties.RemoveAt(i);
            }
        }

        if(Only != null)
        {
            for (int i = properties.Count; i-- > 0; )
            {
                if (!Only.Contains(properties[i].Name)) properties.RemoveAt(i);
            }
        }
        //etc...
        }
```

it takes 2 optional parameters they can be both null or either of them can have a value but at least one of them should be null.

i am trying to figure out the Linq syntax for the above, is there a way to write a where statement but ignore that where statement if the list to compare with is null?

basicly i am looking for a way to write the above using LINQ only.

i cant use Intersect or Except since its between 2 different types

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var result = properties
     .Where(p => !(Except ?? Enumerable.Empty<String>()).Any(s => s == p.Name))
     .Where(p => Only == null || Only.Any(s => s == p.Name))
     .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you don't manage the filtering in that method at all. Instead you can do like this:

```
public static string UpdateCommand<T>(Func<IEnumerable<PropertyInfo>, IEnumerable<PropertyInfo>> filterFunc = null)
{
    IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();

    if (filterFunc != null)
        properties = filterFunc(properties);

    ...
}
```

Use it like this:

```
UpdateCommand(pis => pis.Where(pi => ...))
```

Answer (score 2):

This type of thing was recently discussed [here](http://damieng.com/blog/2013/12/09/probable-c-6-0-features-illustrated)  in an article about possible C# 6.0 features (item 7).  Its not really possible currently without some work arounds, for example as shown in the previous answer.